# Updating data from http request in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I've got an interface that basically lets you add, edit, or delete a user. When the component initializes it does an http request to the server to get current users. So if you go to edit or delete a user there is a dropdown of all the users received from that request. The problem is that if the I delete a user for example through http request, I need to then send another get request to update the data client side so that if you were to open the dropdown again it would reflect the changes made. I can fix this problem by running 'ngOnInit()' again after successful request but this means I'm 'subscribing' every time the user does something..

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getUsers()
   .subscribe(payload => {
      payload.forEach(user => {
         this.users.push(user);
      });
   });
}
```

I'm new to Angular so I'm not entirely sure the best way to go about it but I feel like running this method of 'subscribing' every time the user performs a request is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor out the code that requests for current users in a private method, so that you can reuse it -

```
private loadUsers(): void {
    this.service.getUsers()
        .subscribe(payload => {
            payload.forEach(user => {
                this.users.push(user);
            });
        });
}
```

Then you can call that private method from inside the `ngOnInit()` -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loadUsers();
}
```

and also from inside your delete method, when the deletion is done -

```
deleteUser(id: number): void {
    this.service.deleteUsers(id)
        .subscribe(p => {
            console.log('User deleted Successfully!');
            this.loadUsers();    // reusing loadUsers()
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally It's best if you request the data from the server once you have performed a POST/Delete operation just to be sure that you get the latest/correct data from the server. So Yes, it is OK to get data again after delete.

I have give the code sample below of typically how you can do it. Don't forget to unsubscribe the observables and dispose of them later.

```
private subscriptions = new Subscription();

ngOnInit() {
  this.refreshList()
}

deleteUser(id: string) {
        this.subscriptions.add(
            this.service.deleteUser(id).subscribe(
                success => {
                    this.notificationService.showNotification(`User deleted: ${success.name}`);
                    this.refreshList();
                },
                errors => this.notificationService.showErrors('Error deleting User', errors)
            )
        );
    }

refreshList() {
this.subscriptions.add(
 this.service.getUsers()
   .subscribe(payload => {
        this.users = payload;         
   }));
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is removing the deleted user from the `users` array locally inside your class after you get success response from the delete request. Do not use `this.ngOnInit();` and of course don't subscribe again to the same api to get the new data.

Let's say that you get the `id` of the user you want to delete and send this id to through the `delete api`, you save it in a poroperty `userId`. Then:

1. get user index in the `users` array:
   `let deletedUserIndex = this.users.findIndex(item => item.id === this.userId);`
2. delete the user object from the users array:
   `this.users.splice(deletedUserIndex, 1);`

And that's it